# Can you transfer your Eyepet save to Eyepet & Friends?

Tags: eyepet

I have both Eyepet (original addition, upgraded to Move Edition) and the new Eyepet & Friends. I have a saved character for the first game on my system.

Upon starting the new game, it seemed to do some kind of import, after it finished (it seemed to take a while, as it checked data on every account on my system), I expected it to import my save file, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as non of my old pets appear in the new game. I can only guess the import was for previous DLC.

Does anyone know if it's possible to import pets from the previous game into the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having tested further, I can only conclude that sadly this isn't possible. The new game doesn't take into account the save from the previous game.